# moving a opencv visual studio project

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been working on a opencv project with visual studio 2013 and the version of opencv is 2.4.8. The problem I am having is when I move the .exe file that is produced from the visual studio to another location it complains about not finding the .dll files from the opencv library, which are located in C:\opencv directory. Here is the error message:

```
    System error: The Program can't start because opencv_core248d.dll is missing from your
    computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: also the program compiles in vs so I don't think I need to re-install opencv.

Comment: Visual Studio presumably knows where the opencv stuff is and makes sure the dlls needed are loaded, try putting your .exe in c:\opencv and see if that works better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need to add the directory that contains all those dlls to your [system PATH](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx), or put all those needed dlls in the same directory as the executable(or your executable where your dlls are located). They are DYNAMIC libraries, so the program needs access to them when it tries to execute.